# Forcing animations to play in real time, ignoring time scale

Tags: unity, c#, animation, animator, deltatime

When the character dies, an animation plays, and then the scene resets. What I want is that nothing moves/animates except the character and the life bar so I use `Time.deltaTime = 0;` to do this but it also stops my character and the life bar. Is there a way to force a specific animator to use real delta time?

Comment: Presumably you looked at [AnimatorUpdateMode.UnscaledTime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimatorUpdateMode.UnscaledTime.html)? Did you encounter any difficulty using this to solve your problem?

Comment: Oh, thanks. I overlooked that

Comment: If that solves your problem, be sure to write up your solution as an answer so it can help the next user searching for a way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So for those who have the same question, I've found what needs to be modified:
On the animator Component, there is a drop-down menu named "Update Mode" which has three options:

- Normal (in-sync with Update method)
- Animate Physics (in-sync with FixedUpdate method)
- Unscaled Time (in-sync with Update method, but uses unscaled time)

Use the third one if you have the same problem as me. Also here's a picture from unity's documentation about the animator component:

[image: Animator Component]

EDIT: I don't know why is this happening but in my case I set `Time.timeScale` to `0.01f` instead of `0` and then everything worked as I excepted